# Visual Studio 2008 - Get time interval between break points?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Does anyone know if you can get the time interval between break points in VS 2008? Plugin?, VS trick?

I DON'T want to add code to my existing source code to figure out how long something takes to run, I would like a quick and dirty way to get this while debugging. For you smart asses out there I know I can always whip out a stopwatch too, but I want something that is somewhat precise as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a Tracepoint - which, when hit, will output what you entered to the console window:

[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/3866/51292677.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/3866/51292677.png)

Then you can subtract the latter from the former to get the time between the two.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. If your code takes a couple of seconds to run you could also use {DateTime.Now.Second}

Comment: @PhilipWallace - So? The question is not C#-specific. He just happened to be using C#.

Comment: @Sinatr A [tracepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_Print_to_the_Output_window_with_tracepoints) is a point in code where something is printed to the output window instead of halting program execution. Unfortunately the image link is gone, but I suppose Phillip Wallace meant to print the $TICK variable at each tracepoint (see my link for $TICK definition). Unfortunately I tried doing this myself in Visual C++ (VS2017) and just got 2 hex values which don't seem to mean anything.

Answer (score 6):

Add two watches:

```
@clk
@clk = 0
```

The debugger evaluates them top to bottom, so `@clk` will show the time take on that debugger step, and `@clk = 0` will reset it back to 0 again for the next step.

Comment: Where is a source on this clk variable? I get an unsigned int like "1861728" which I am not sure how to interpret -- is it just the number of milliseconds? EDIT: After following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750256/visual-studio-c-2013-code-stopwatch-with-clk?noredirect=1&lq=1) I got to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/pseudovariables) by Hans Passant's comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are some useful tricks you can use in this regard with the @clk debug macro.  It gives the current timestamp.

At the first breakpoint you add a watch of @clk=0.  That resets it to zero.
At the second breakpoint look at the value of @clk - it will be the duration since the first breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of anything to do that, but maybe you can use the performance wizard to get some useful (timing) information.
On the other hand you can print a message on each hit, you could print the current time.

Comment: -1 because you start off by saying you can't think of anything.