# Visual Studio c++ 2013 Code stopwatch with $clk

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, stopwatch

I'm trying to measure the execution time of code without using additional functions(stopwatch class). Like this thread says [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690505/visual-studio-2008-get-time-interval-between-break-points) im using @clk (according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164891.aspx) also $clk), but the debugger always throws "$clk undeclared identifier" when accessing $clk in code or "identifier '$clk' out of scope" when writing it into the watch/tracepoint.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is a [pseudo-variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx) to the debugger.  It still works fine in VS2013 in a *native* C++ project.  It is quite unsuitable to measure code execution time, you just can't press the F5 key fast enough.  Use QueryPerformancCounter() or QueryThreadCycleTime() in your program instead.  Or the profiler.

Comment: $clk works for me in watch, but not in a tracepoint.  I would just go with a stopwatch class with #ifdef _DEBUG, and do it in code.